# Application layer testing using a replacment/mock library

Tags: c++, testing, c++11, mocking

We have a native C++ library of business functionality that has several UI's built on it (web, web service, desktop).  The library has a large (and growing) portion of library level unit & integration tests.

I am looking for a way to test the various UI layers without duplicating the testing that is done in the library level unit & integration tests.

My current thought is to create (in a hopefully mostly automated way) a mock version of the library.  The mock version of the library would do structured logging of the incoming calls & their parameters, and provide consistent static return values.  We could then put the mock library/engine under each product and try to ensure that the UI/upper layers of the application are correctly connected to the library.

**Question/s**

1. Is there a better way?
2. Are there any tools to make the mock library generation easier?

Comment: Even if you successfully recreate the mock library, you'll need some way to control the values it returns so that you can properly test that the UI is going to do the right thing with the range of output generated by library.

Comment: @jxh, Good point.  I may be trivializing the effort that will be required to both log API inputs, and provide relevant outputs to check the UI layers.

Comment: How separable are the UIs?  How stateful?  (I'm assuming the library is stateful)  A nearly stateless UI could be tested without the library by simply throwing valid library states at it, and having it send requests at the library: but a UI whose state is intended to vary along with the libraries state has limited testability without a library.  Now, testing it with a library that does not behave like the normal library makes lots of sense: a library that returns errors more often, or does other unexpected actions.